# Chrome packaged app window maximizes to full-screen on Windows 8

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When I maximize a packaged app window (created using chrome.app.window.create) on Windows 8 it is maximized to full-screen (hiding the taskbar).

Is there a way for the chrome window to be maximized normally and not in full-screen ? (leaving the taskbar visible)

Comment: Does this happen on Windows 7? I only have Windows 7 available to test right now and it doesn't happen for me.

Comment: I have seen this happen on Windows 7 only occasionally (couldn't reproduce) , but I can confirm that on Windows 8 it will take up the whole screen (including taskbar & any other 'side' metro app) .. I have tested this using the 'Simple Text Editor' app.. Screenshot Before Maximize: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eBtw7.jpg , After Maximize: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WsRaN.png

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is somewhat outdated, but somehow the issue still persists, and I think I found a temporary solution.

You can use the `chrome.system.display` API to query the usable area of the screen, and then set that as the width/height of the window:

```
chrome.system.display.getInfo(function(info) {
    var width = info[0].workArea.width;
    var height = info[0].workArea.height;
    chrome.app.window.create(url, {
        bounds: {
            width: width,
            height: height
        },
    });
});
```

`chrome.system.display.getInfo()` returns an object with data regarding the display(s), inside of which the `workArea` property specifies the usable height/width. Just remember to include the `system.display` permission in the app manifest! You can read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display.html).

Definitely a hack, but it works.

Comment: was having same issue and this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It should maximize without hiding the titlebar. I haven't verified this, but I have filed a chromium issue for the bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224924.